# Find the points of continuity (Calculus II)

Tags: calculus, continuity

$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases}     \frac{x - 3y}{x^2 + y^2}, & \text{if } (x, y) \neq (0, 0) \\     0, & \text{if } (x, y) = (0, 0) \end{cases}$$

So, I tried to do it like this:
If $(x, y) \neq (0, 0)$, so

$$ f(x, y) = \frac{x - 3y}{x^2 + y^2} $$

and

$$ f(x, y) = \frac{x_0 - 3y_0}{x_0^2 + y_0^2} $$

\begin{align*}
\lim_{{(x, y) \to (x_0, y_0)}} \frac{{x - 3y}}{{x^2 + y^2}} &= \frac{{x_0 - 3y_0}}{{x_0^2 + y_0^2}} \\
&= f(x_0, y_0)
\end{align*}

So, $f(x, y)$ is continue in $(x_0, y_0) \neq (0, 0)$.

If $(x, y) = (0, 0)$, (From that part, I couldn't do it anymore)

Comment: Try converting to polar coordinates.

Comment: Limit along $x=y$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

**Proving the Limit Does Not Exist**
When trying to disprove a limit in multivariable limits, it's common to examine along various approaches.
**A.i.** For example, as @geetha290km suggests try approaching along the line $y=x$.  It turns out this by itself is sufficient when simplified.
**A.ii.** If that didn't work we could try, letting $y=0$ and approaching along the x-axis.
**A.iii.** If that didn't work we could try, letting $x=0$ and approaching along the y-axis.
For the limit to exist, all three must exist and be equal to each other.  Failure at any of the four conditions, existence of i, ii, iii or them being equal to each other is enough to say the limit does not exist.  See note B below
This limit does not exist.  **A.i.** is likely the simplest method.

**Proving the Limit Does Exist**
Proving a limit exists can be more difficult.  Any sufficient approach will incorporate all possible approaches to the limit point, $(0,0)$ in this case.  Even exotic approaches like spirals.  Converting to polar or for 3 dimensional domains to spherical coordinates and letting the radius go to zero often works.

Note B: None of the criteria A are sufficient to prove the limit exists; these can only prove the limit does *not* exist.

For the record this topic is usually taught in Calculus III, but which topics go in which course does vary from one university to the next.